# _stdcall function returning 0xCCCCCC01

Tags: assembly

I have a simple function that just returns a boolean (Right now set to returning true). I'm trying to write an assembly function that will call it, and jump based on the return value.

Sadly my function is returning 0xCCCCCC01 instead of the expected 0x01. Is this some hidden feature of stdcall?

Comment: Show your function, and how you read its return value. (I'm sure you have realized that 0x01 is the LSB of the value you are getting, and CCCC... is what VS sets uninitialised memory to as far as I know, so I'm pretty certain you're only reading it wrong.)

Comment: Sometimes the easiest way to do this is to cheat: write the function in C, and either have the compiler generate assembly output, or disassemble the result.

Comment: I actually just looked at the code generated for the function. Turns out booleans are stored in AL, not EAX. That explains why the lower bits are set correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `_stdcall`, the return value is passed in `EAX`.

However, if you're returning a boolean from a function, and your boolean is only one byte [*], you can't use `CMP EAX,...` to compare the return value!

Fortunately, you can address the lowest of `EAX` through `AL` (it's not a separate register, but part of `EAX`):

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
----------------EAX----------------
                  --------AX-------
                  ---AH--- ---AL---
```

---

[*] this is the usual convention, as it is the minimum amount you need to be able to address booleans properly via byte pointers. If you come up with your own language though, you are free to require that boolean size must match machine register size.

Answer (score 1):

What language is the function written in? Maybe boolean is one byte long in that language. In Apple's dialect of Objective C, notably, BOOL is `typedef`fed as `char`.

If that's the case, your return value is AL, not EAX.

You should really tag the question with the platform/compiler/OS/language.